# Traversing a large network using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large data set with individuals and some of their details. The data set contains large number of duplicates and a large number of records "relate" to each other based on one of their features. To ensure that correct records are linked a match on 2 out of 3 features will be counted as a link. Each individual will need to be linked to all possible records and each one of them will be allocated a clusterId.

I have a following data set structure:

```
+--+----+----+----+
|id|col1|col2|col3|
+--+----+----+----+
|1 |A   |B   |C   |
+--+----+----+----+
|2 |A   |B   |D   |
+--+----+----+----+
|3 |A   |Z   |D   |
+--+----+----+----+
```

Id 1 will be linked to id 2 (as col1 and col2 are the same) and id 2 will be linked to id 3 (as col1 and col3 are the same). Linking id 1 and 2 added some more information to this "cluster" and after that link is established id 3 should belong to that cluster.

The data set is very large (28 million records) and I have no good idea that will allow me to build these relationships within a reasonable time frame.

Any ideas what would be the quickest and most elegant way of solving this?

Comment: Throw out the broken schema and renormalise your data!

Comment: Each row represents an individual and this data has been normalised. I am sure that the schema could be improved - could you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

With that much data, creating the relationships will likely be slow, but if your columns are indexed and you have a fast server, it may not be too bad. Create a table to store the relationships. This SQL should populate the relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE RelationshipTable
    ([id1] int, [id2] int,[cluster] int);   

INSERT INTO RelationshipTable
    SELECT a.id,b.id,NULL
    FROM TestTable a
    LEFT JOIN TestTable b ON a.id<>b.id AND (
        (
                    ((a.col1 is null and b.col1 is null) or a.col1=b.col1)
                and ((a.col2 is null and b.col2 is null) or a.col2=b.col2)
        )
        OR
        (
                    ((a.col1 is null and b.col1 is null) or a.col1=b.col1)
                and ((a.col3 is null and b.col3 is null) or a.col3=b.col3)
        )
        OR
        (
                    ((a.col2 is null and b.col2 is null) or a.col2=b.col2)
                and ((a.col3 is null and b.col3 is null) or a.col3=b.col3)
        )
    )

DECLARE @UpdateId INT
DECLARE @ClusterId INT
SET @ClusterId=0

WHILE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM RelationshipTable
    WHERE [cluster] IS NULL
)
BEGIN
  SET @ClusterId=@ClusterId+1

  SELECT
    @UpdateId=[id1]
  FROM RelationshipTable
  WHERE [cluster] IS NULL

  UPDATE RelationshipTable
  SET [cluster]=@ClusterId
  WHERE ID1=@UpdateId
  OR ID2=@UpdateId

  WHILE @@Rowcount>0
  BEGIN
    UPDATE RelationshipTable
    SET [cluster]=@ClusterId
    WHERE [cluster] IS NULL
    AND
    (
      ID1 IN (
           SELECT ID1
           FROM RelationshipTable
           WHERE [cluster]=@ClusterId
           UNION
           SELECT ID2
           FROM RelationshipTable
           WHERE [cluster]=@ClusterId
      )
      OR ID2 IN (
           SELECT ID1
           FROM RelationshipTable
           WHERE [cluster]=@ClusterId
           UNION
           SELECT ID2
           FROM RelationshipTable
           WHERE [cluster]=@ClusterId
      )
    )
  END
END

select * from RelationshipTable
```

Comment: Creating the relationships is slow, but will run in under 24 hours on the hardware available. However this only creates a one to one relationship between records and not the clustered view I am after. Ie. this will join id 1 to id 2 and id 2 to id 3 but not id 1 to id 3.

Comment: @wujtehacjusz Updated based on what I think your end goal is. This is certainly not very efficient, but I can't think of a better way. It failed to work in SQL Fiddle, but worked find in SQL Server.